# Restrict Product Backlog Ordering/Prioritization in TFS2012

Tags: tfs, permissions, drag-and-drop, scrum

Is it possible to restrict the ability to reorder items via drag-and-drop when viewing the Product Backlog in TFS2012?  We want only certain groups to have the ability to reorder PBIs using the drag-and-drop functionality in Team Web Access.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to edit the backlog xml file and make it the backlog priority field readonly for particular groups of users.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsprocess/thread/86635b29-be54-4c26-b918-0244f9d502c1/

That probably wont stop you dragging them around, but it will likely error and not save if they do.